# Using SQLAlchemy Base-derived classes in FastAPI routes (FastAPI workflow)

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I made the `class User(Base):` (SQLAlchemy-related) and want to use it inside my FastAPI routes because I do not want to make another duplicate BaseModel-class with the exact same definition:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)

    username = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)

    created_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
```

```
@app.post("/user")
async def create_user(user: User) -> Any:
    return None
```

but seems it's not possible to use the `class User(Base):` otherwise you get the error

```
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'db.User'> is a valid Pydantic field type.
```

What do you do if you want to use your SQLAlchemy Base-derived classes in routes? Is it possible to do so? Are you forced to create duplicate analog classes but derived from BaseModel in order to use such classes in FastAPI routes?

Comment: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/ - a hybrid framework between Pydantic and SQLAlchemy by the same main author as behind FastAPI.

Comment: As @MatsLindh says, SQLModel is a good option. However, in my experience there is almost always a couple of fields that differ vetween the two (you probably don't want `created_on` and `updated_on` to be altered by the client, and `id` might also be autogenerated), so you end up needing to separate your database models from your API schemas anyway.

Comment: I'd also like to say that I fully agree with M.O. - you usually end up with the request and response formats differing from what you have in your databases. Remember that you can use inheritance to build extended/adopted versions of your request/response models.

Comment: This makes sense, @MatsLindh. I was getting a feeling I must be doing something wrong.